# Using GoogleAPIClient in Background Services

Tags: android, service, background, gcmtaskservice

My scenario is that I would like to have a service periodically obtain some information (eg. location of user), report it to my server and receive a push notification if the location matches some X location.

I would to get some advice on what would be the best mechanism to periodically retrieve location information regardless of whether the application is running or not. Here are the options that I have thought about and some background information on each.

**Creating a Standard Android Service**

My first thought was to create a STICKY service that initializes a GoogleAPIClient that will get location updates and once a location is received, it will send it to the server. The problem I have with this approach is that I have to periodically get the location information. So the service would be running constantly even if it is not running a location scan. Also what would be the best way to poll for location every so often within a service?

**Creating an Alarm with IntentService**

The second option I thought about was having the Alarm Manager wake up and start an IntentService which starts location updates (via GoogleAPIClient). Once a location is obtained send to the server and close the location updates. This would solve the issue of periodically starting/stoping location updates. However, I haven't had much luck connecting to GoogleAPIClient within the IntentService without putting a wait and I don't think that is the most efficient thing to do.

**Creating a GcmTaskService**

This has many advantages of the AlarmManager and seems to be more efficient in terms of doze mode as it only wakes up the Service whenever the phone is in a maintenance mode so it seemed like a good solution. However, I have the same issue as the IntentService which is connecting to a GoogleAPIClient to get location without some sort of wait.

I may be going too far down the rabbit hole on this one and there may be something obvious I am missing so any advice would be great appreciated.

Comment: did you figure out best solution?

Comment: I am now using a WorkManager with a Worker that runs every 15 minutes. It's much better on battery and I managed to cover most use cases, for scenarios where location was needed more frequently over a specific time period a foreground service with a notification was created as per https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground. Alternating between the options seems to work very well especially on battery based on what the user is looking for.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. I went for the first approach (a sticky service) and everything worked fine. However, I didn't like the fact that the service was always running and visible to the user.
That's why I decided to use the JobScheduler API as it's the preferred way of performing background work according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#background_optimizations).

If your app targets API>=21 then JobScheduler is the way to go. If you want to support older versions of the platform then you should use the recently introduced [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) library, which unfortunately lacks of documentation.

Everything is explained [here](https://youtu.be/VC2Hlb22mZM?t=22m10s) at a Google I/O 2016 presentation. Take a look at it.

Comment: Ya that's what I was thinking as well. How did you handle connecting to the GoogleAPIClient within your JobScheduler? Using the blockingConnect with a timeout or another method?

Comment: I use the non blocking [connect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()) method and then I handle the job depending on the connection result(methods onConnected, onConnectionFailed).

Answer (score 0):

When you request updates, you can request a maximum frequency.  Just use a service and set the maximum frequency equal to the polling interval you want.  No AlarmManager needed.

Comment: I thought about that I just wasn't sure if it was the most efficient approach if the maximum frequency is going to be several hours apart (its user defined). I thought maybe starting/stoping the FusedLocationApi was more efficient.