# Android scheduled background/foreground service with notification

Tags: android, service, background, notifications, scheduled-tasks

What is the best approach to implement a service which executes every 15 mins.
Execution should happen when app is killed / in the background and even when it's running.
It should do some http work which is already works fine but with asynctask.
If this http returns with a particular data, it should show a notification.
How should i do this?
Any help is greatly appriciated.
I'm fine if you just mention approaches, methods, patterns, best practices, etc..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best approach to implement a service which executes every
>   15 mins.

Using the Job Scheduler. Information on job scheduling can be found at the [Intelligent Job-Scheduling documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html). However, be aware that you can't be 100% sure that your service is going to run exactly every 15 minutes as its execution can be affected by the Doze mode and its [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#restrictions).

For the notification part, you [build your notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) as you would normally do.

If you need more info, you may view the [Using the Android Job Scheduler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdINLG5QrJc) and [Background work with JobScheduler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFN3MrnNhZA) videos and check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-JobScheduler) sample project. Also, one relevant question regarding the repetitive nature of the service can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089169).

Comment: Thank you sir!
I'm going to read all of the mentioned resources.